# How to convert a int to byte?

Tags: java, arraylist, int, byte, arrays

I just trying to figure out how to convert an int number into byte.
It sounds easy, but for me it's hard to know how to convert it.

For e.g:

```
    public byte[] getByteArray(String ipOrMac){

        String[] temp = new String[0];
        ArrayList<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        if(ipOrMac.contains(":")){
            temp = ipOrMac.split(":"); // this makes temp into a new Array
                                       //with splitted strings
        }

        if(ipOrMac.contains(".")){
            temp = ipOrMac.split(".");
        }

        for(int a = 0; a<=temp.length-1; a++){
            intList.add(Integer.parseInt(temp[a]));
        }

//      System.out.println(stringList.toArray()[0]);
//      for(int a = 0; a<=stringList.size()-1; a++){
//          stringList.
//      }

        return null;
    }
```

My maintarget is to get a String like this "2:2:2:2" (it's a mac-adress)
into a byte[].
So now I have the problem to convert all the ints in my arraylist-integer to bytes.
I don't want to use an arraylist-byte because it's inefficient...

So any ideas?

Hope you can help me. :)

Comment: *"I don't want to use an arraylist-byte because it's inefficient..."* Programs get slow because they do too many things. Unless you're doing something with a `List` like a million times, there's no reason to even think about micro-optimization, let alone design your program around it.

Comment: @Radiodef, cue obligatory "premature optimization is the root of all evil".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following snippet of code:

```
String[] temp = ipOrMac.split(ipOrMac.contains(":") ? ":" : "\\.");

byte[] array = new byte[temp.length];

for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; ++i)
    array[i] = (byte)Integer.parseInt(temp[i]);
```

Comment: Same solution with less lines. ty

Comment: Now I have to avoid the negative numbers.

Comment: It's me again. String.split(".") can't recognize the ".".... why?

Comment: Ok found the mistake. For "." I have to use String.split(Pattern.quote(".")); :)

Comment: @Cem, yes, you're right. You should use `"\\."` instead of `"."`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead, write

```
    byte[] bytes = new byte[temp.length];
    for(int a = 0; a< temp.length; a++){
        bytes[a] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(temp[a]);
    }
    return bytes;
```

Comment: Jap thats good. Now I have to avoid the negative numbers 0 to -127. :) Thank you!

Comment: @Cem it is very important to understand that no, you do not.  Having those negative bytes is *correct.*

Comment: Yeah but you can't have negative numbers in mac- or ipadresse.

Comment: @Cem the proper solution is to treat those bytes as unsigned or expect that other APIs handle them correctly.  Understanding that negative bytes are not actually wrong is very important to getting Java right.

Comment: I have to look in the docu. But I think that the API is handling the byte correctly. I'm using jnetpcap to create a pcap with many packets..

Comment: Ah i just got the problem..hm i need to think how to handle ipnumbers which a bigger than 127. So the affected numbers are from 128 to 255.

Answer (score 1):

How about this example:

(Full code: https://github.com/anjalshireesh/gluster-ovirt-poc/blob/master/backend/manager/modules/utils/src/test/java/org/ovirt/engine/core/utils/jwin32/AppTest.java#L153 )

```
    try {
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(16);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);

        String[] arrSidParts = strSid.split("-");
        for (int i = 4; i < arrSidParts.length; i++) {
            bb.putInt((int) Long.parseLong(arrSidParts[i]));
        }

        Guid guid = new Guid(bb.array(), false);
        out.println(guid.toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        out.println("!" + e.getMessage() + "!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Those the ByteBuffer automatically avoid the negative numbers ? (From 0 to -127) ?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly... you want to convert the string to byte[], right?

You just need to do this:

byte[] ipOrMacBytes = ipOrMac.getBytes();

Comment: This is not likely to accomplish what the OP wants, which is to get the actual numerical value of the numbers in the string.